# how to find shortpath in Orientdb (edges instead of vertexes)

Tags: java, orientdb

I have this graph:
       A-->B, A-->C, B-->C, C-->D, A-->E

I want to find the shortest path between "A" and "D" in java. I used:

```
s= select from ( select expand( shortestPath("+ first_vertex.getId() +", "+ second_vertex.getId() +").outE()))

    for (Edge edge : (Iterable<Edge>) g.command(
        new OCommandSQL(s)).execute()) {
            System.out.println(edge);
        }
```

The problem I get not the desired result:

```
      A - B
      A - C
      A - E 
      C - D
```

When I focus in vertex instead of Edges I got the correct short path which is:
A -> C -> D

Why edges is not working as I did?

EDIT:

[Updated graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7X2.png)

When I have the graph as it is in the attached image and I want to find the shortest path between "A" and "D" using your method still I got no edges: SHORTEST PATH (vertex): A C D SHORTEST PATH (edge): shouldn't the SHORTEST PATH (vertex) be: A, F, E, D ?. If I want to find the shortest path between "D" and "A" now I also get no edages after your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new answer because the code is quite different from the previous one.
With this code you just set StartNode (Vstart) & endNode (Vend), and returns the ShortestPath (referring to edge) with direction 'out' (compared to the first node) and direction 'in' (if present) always compared to the first node.
The operation is based on extracting vertices who returned from work ShortestPath() of orient,for each of these vertices controls the edge.

```
public class PathEdge {


    static final String REMOTE = "remote:localhost/";

    static final String NOMEDB  = "ShortestPath2";
    static final String CURRENTPATH = REMOTE + NOMEDB;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(CURRENTPATH).connect("root", "root");

    OrientGraphNoTx g = new OrientGraphFactory(CURRENTPATH).getNoTx();

    String Vstart   = "a";  //----- to set
    String Vend     = "d";  // ---- to set
    String queryClassName   = "Nodo";  //----- to set
    String queryProperty    = "name"; //----- to set
    String edgeNAme = "is_a";   //----- to set
    String direction = "'OUT'";  //----- to set "BOTH" (incoming and outgoing), "OUT" (outgoing) and "IN" (incoming)

    String query1 = "select from "+queryClassName+" where "+queryProperty+" = '"+Vstart+"'";
    Iterable<Vertex> start = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(query1)).execute();

    String query2 = "select from "+queryClassName+" where "+queryProperty+" = '"+Vend+"'";  
    Iterable<Vertex> end = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(query2)).execute();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    showPath(g, start.iterator().next().getId().toString(), end.iterator().next().getId().toString(), edgeNAme, direction);
    long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("TIME EXECUTE: "+estimatedTime+"ms");
}

public static void showPath (OrientGraphNoTx  g, String Vstart, String Vend , String edge, String direction) {

     String s = "";
     int position = 0;
     int maxsize = 0;

     s= "select expand(shortestPath(" + Vstart + ", " + Vend+", "+direction+"))";

    Iterable<Vertex> result = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(s)).execute();
    List<OrientVertex> listaVertex = new ArrayList<OrientVertex>();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(listaVertex, result.iterator());

    List<String> listPRECout = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listPRECin = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listFOLLout = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listFOLLin = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> resultOut = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> resultIn = new ArrayList<String>();

    //per ogni vertice recupera archi uscenti ed entranti
    Iterable<Edge> tempOut;
    Iterable<Edge> tempIn;
    String singleIn = "";
    String singleOut = "";
    boolean finded = false;

    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (vertex [direction "+direction+"]):");
    for (int v=0; v<listaVertex.size(); v++) {
        System.out.print(listaVertex.get(v).getProperty("name")+ " " );
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    maxsize = listaVertex.size()-1;
    for (int v=0; v<maxsize; v++) {

        //--------FIRST VERTEX OF THE SHORTEST PATH
        tempOut = listaVertex.get(v).getEdges(Direction.OUT, edge);
        tempIn = listaVertex.get(v).getEdges(Direction.IN, edge);

        //set listPRECin 
        for(Edge edgeIn : tempIn) {
            listPRECin.add(edgeIn.getId().toString());  //position x   = rid
            listPRECin.add(edgeIn.getLabel());          //position x+1 = label
        }

        //set listPRECout 
        for(Edge edgeOut : tempOut) {
            listPRECout.add(edgeOut.getId().toString());  //position x   = rid
            listPRECout.add(edgeOut.getLabel());          //position x+1 = label
        }

        //--------SECOND VERTEX OF THE SHORTEST PATH
        tempOut = listaVertex.get(v+1).getEdges(Direction.OUT, edge);
        tempIn = listaVertex.get(v+1).getEdges(Direction.IN, edge);

        //set listFOLLin 
        for(Edge edgeIn : tempIn) {
            listFOLLin.add(edgeIn.getId().toString());  //position x   = rid
            listFOLLin.add(edgeIn.getLabel());          //position x+1 = label
        }

        //set listFOLLout 
        for(Edge edgeOut : tempOut) {
            listFOLLout.add(edgeOut.getId().toString());  //position x   = rid
            listFOLLout.add(edgeOut.getLabel());          //position x+1 = label
        }


        //------MATCH LOGIC
        //...compare PRECin with FOLLout
        finded = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<listPRECin.size(); i=i+2) {
            singleIn = listPRECin.get(i);
            for(int o = 0; o<listFOLLout.size(); o=o+2){
                singleOut = listFOLLout.get(o);
                if(singleIn.equals(singleOut)) {

                    //check is there a hole
                    if(v==0) {
                        resultIn.add(singleIn);  //rid
                        resultIn.add(listPRECin.get(i+1)); //label
                        finded = true;
                        break; 
                    } else if((v*2) == resultIn.size()) {
                        resultIn.add(singleIn);  //rid
                        resultIn.add(listPRECin.get(i+1)); //label
                        finded = true;
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(finded)break;    
        }

        finded = false;
        //...compare PRECout with FOLLin
        for(int i = 0; i<listPRECout.size(); i=i+2) {
            singleOut = listPRECout.get(i);
            for(int o = 0; o<listFOLLin.size(); o=o+2){
                singleIn = listFOLLin.get(o);
                if(singleOut.equals(singleIn)) {
                    //check is there a hole
                    if(v==0) {
                        resultOut.add(singleOut);  //rid
                        resultOut.add(listPRECout.get(i+1)); //label
                        finded = true;
                        break; 
                    } else if((v*2) == resultOut.size()) {
                        resultOut.add(singleOut);  //rid
                        resultOut.add(listPRECout.get(i+1)); //label
                        finded = true;
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(finded)break;    
        }

        //to empty out list
        listPRECin.clear();
        listPRECout.clear();    
        listFOLLin.clear();
        listFOLLout.clear();    

        //cheack if it's in the penultimate vertex
        position = v+1;
        if( position==maxsize) {
            break;
        }

    }


    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (edge, out direction):");
    if(resultOut.size()>0) {
        for (int ind=0; ind<resultOut.size(); ind=ind+2) {  //ind+2 so i get id[position x] and label [position x+1] 
            System.out.println("id:"+resultOut.get(ind)+", Label:"+resultOut.get(ind+1));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No edge in this direction (OUT)");
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (edge, in direction):");
    if(resultIn.size()>0) {
        for (int ind=0; ind<resultIn.size(); ind=ind+2) {  //ind+2 so i get id[position x] and label [position x+1] 
            System.out.println("id:"+resultIn.get(ind)+", Label:"+resultIn.get(ind+1));
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("No edge in this direction (IN)");
    }

}
```

}

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Using the 'direction' in the ShortestPath function.
[image]

Comment: I applied the code on my graph (see my first EDIT). I got only the shortest "in" path direction (A-C-D). Suppose I am interested to have the "out" direction from "A" to "D" then the shortest path should be "A-F-E-D" and not "No edge in this direction (OUT)"

Comment: Your graph is connected in this way:
A -> C;
A -> F;
A -> E;
A -> B;
B -> C;
C -> A;
C -> D;
D -> C;
E -> D;
F -> E;
(image of answeer 2)
is it right?

If this is correct (exactly these edge), applying the code that I wrote in response 2, you should get the code that I put in the image of the response 2.
SHORTEST PATH (vertex): a c d 
SHORTEST PATH (edge, out):
id:#13:1, Label:collega
id:#13:4, Label:collega
SHORTEST PATH (edge, in ):
id:#13:9, Label:collega
id:#13:8, Label:collega
 
If you do not come out this result, can I ask if you send me your db? if you want to leave you my email.

Comment: Not exactly. Here is the Graph (http://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7X2.png). The question is how to find the shortest path for Edge "IN" or Edge "Out". Using my code if I give "IN" then I get the shortest path "A-C-D" for Edge "IN". If I give "OUT" then I get the shortest path "A-F-E-D" for edge out. Tell me if you still need the database.

Comment: ok perfect, no I do not need more db, I reproduce your pattern and do some testing. I will let you know.

Comment: I modified the code in the response 2, adding that it is possible specidicare the direction in ShortestPath function (Start, End, 'In or Out or Both').
Example:------------result for 'IN'
SHORTEST PATH (vertex [direction 'IN']):
a c d 

SHORTEST PATH (edge, out direction):
No edge in this direction (OUT)

SHORTEST PATH (edge, in direction):
id:#13:3, Label:is_a
id:#13:4, Label:is_a

Comment: ---------------result for 'OUT'
SHORTEST PATH (vertex [direction 'OUT']):
a f e d 

SHORTEST PATH (edge, out direction):
id:#13:1, Label:is_a
id:#13:6, Label:is_a
id:#13:5, Label:is_a

SHORTEST PATH (edge, in direction):
No edge in this direction (IN)

Comment: All this because the edge that are obtained as a result of the resulting vertex returned from ShortestPath function. Without specifying the direction, the ShortestPath function returns you the shortest path (in your case "a c d" and not "a f e d"). With the edit 2 in the answer 2 is more clear.

Comment: It works perfect and much efficient. I will make rich efficiency test in the next few days and report it here.

Comment: I tested both code in a 20 Million Triple data and the standard methods were clearly efficient. I even was interested only in the "OUT" shortest path and the standard method still much efficient.

Comment: ok perfect, the latest version of the code should be more complete and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'select expand(shortestpath(...))' only returns vertices.

Starting from your initial situation.
[image]

Your goal is to extract the edges forming the shortest path (I think I understand), so to have the following result:
[image]

One way to do this would be:
- Find the shortest path (with Vertex)
- get for individual Vertices of the shortest path, the edges connecting the first vertex until the last Vertex.

```
static final String REMOTE = "remote:localhost/";

static final String NOMEDB  = "shortpath";
static final String CURRENTPATH = REMOTE + NOMEDB;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(CURRENTPATH).connect("root", "root");

    OrientGraphNoTx g = new OrientGraphFactory(CURRENTPATH).getNoTx();

    showPath(g);
}

public static void showPath (OrientGraphNoTx  g) {
    String s = "";
    String V1 = "#12:0"; //Vertex A
    String V2 = "#12:3"; //Vertex D
    s= "select expand(shortestPath(" + V1 + ", " + V2+"))";

    Iterable<Vertex> result = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(s)).execute();
    List<OrientVertex> listaVertex = new ArrayList<OrientVertex>();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(listaVertex, result.iterator());

    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> edgePath = new ArrayList<String>();

    //for each vertices get edge out & in
    Iterable<Edge> tempOut;
    Iterable<Edge> tempIn;
    String singleIn = "";
    String singleOut = "";

    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (vertex):");
    for (int v=0; v<listaVertex.size(); v++) {
        System.out.print(listaVertex.get(v).getProperty("name")+ " " );
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i=0; i<listaVertex.size(); i++) {

        tempOut = listaVertex.get(i).getEdges(Direction.OUT, "collega");
        tempIn = listaVertex.get(i).getEdges(Direction.IN, "collega");

        //get edge in
        for(Edge edgeIn : tempIn) {
            in.add(edgeIn.getId().toString());
        }

        //forech edge in, check if is in out
        for(int x=0; x<in.size(); x++) {
            singleIn = in.get(x);
            for(int z=0; z<out.size(); z++) {
                singleOut = out.get(z);
                if(singleIn.equals(singleOut)) {
                    edgePath.add(singleIn);
                }
            }
        }

        //to empty out list
        out.clear();

        //get edge out
        for(Edge edgeOut : tempOut) {
            out.add(edgeOut.getId().toString());
        }

        //to empty in list
        in.clear();

    }

    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (edge):");
    for (int ind=0; ind<edgePath.size(); ind++) {
        System.out.println(edgePath.get(ind));
    }

}
```

The result you get is this:

[image]

A --#13:1--> C --13:4--> D

**EDIT 1**

Definitely an improvement is this:

```
//forech edge in, check if is in out
        boolean finded = false;                        //*******new
        for(int x=0; x<in.size(); x++) {
            singleIn = in.get(x);
            for(int z=0; z<out.size(); z++) {
                singleOut = out.get(z);
                if(singleIn.equals(singleOut)) {
                    edgePath.add(singleIn);
                    finded = true;          //*******new
                    break;              //*******new
                }
            } 
            if(finded)break;                //*******new
        }
```

avoids unnecessary checks.

**EDIT 2**

Added edge label in the result.

```
public static void showPath (OrientGraphNoTx  g) {
    String s = "";
    String V1 = "#12:0"; //Vertex A
    String V2 = "#12:3"; //Vertex D
    s= "select expand(shortestPath(" + V1 + ", " + V2+"))";

    Iterable<Vertex> result = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(s)).execute();
    List<OrientVertex> listaVertex = new ArrayList<OrientVertex>();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(listaVertex, result.iterator());

    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> inLabel = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> edgePath = new ArrayList<String>();

    //per ogni vertice recupera archi uscenti ed entranti
    Iterable<Edge> tempOut;
    Iterable<Edge> tempIn;
    String singleIn = "";
    String singleOut = "";

    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (vertex):");
    for (int v=0; v<listaVertex.size(); v++) {
        System.out.print(listaVertex.get(v).getProperty("name")+ " " );
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i=0; i<listaVertex.size(); i++) {

        tempOut = listaVertex.get(i).getEdges(Direction.OUT, "collega");
        tempIn = listaVertex.get(i).getEdges(Direction.IN, "collega");

        //get edge in
        for(Edge edgeIn : tempIn) {
            in.add(edgeIn.getId().toString());  //list edge id
            inLabel.add(edgeIn.getLabel());     // list edge label
        }

        //forech edge in, check if is in out
        boolean finded = false;
        for(int x=0; x<in.size(); x++) {
            singleIn = in.get(x);
            for(int z=0; z<out.size(); z++) {
                singleOut = out.get(z);
                if(singleIn.equals(singleOut)) {
                    edgePath.add(singleIn);   //in edgePath[position] = id
                    edgePath.add(inLabel.get(x));   //in edgePAth[position+1] = label
                    finded = true;
                    break; 
                }
            } 
            if(finded)break;    
        }

        //to empty out list
        out.clear();

        //get edge out
        for(Edge edgeOut : tempOut) {
            out.add(edgeOut.getId().toString());
        }

        //to empty in list
        in.clear();

    }

    System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH (edge):");
    for (int ind=0; ind<edgePath.size(); ind=ind+2) {  //ind+2 so i get id[position x] and label [position x+1] 
        System.out.println("id:"+edgePath.get(ind)+", Label:"+edgePath.get(ind+1));
    }

}
```

This is the result:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

With the addition of new vertices, the graph should be this. (Is it correct?)
[image]

Starting from this graph, we have:

1)  from "A" to "D"
    SHORTEST PATH(vertex):  is A-C-D (correct with you)
    SHORTEST PATH(edge):  is edgeA-C, edgeC-D

[image]

2)  from "D" to "A"
    SHORTEST PATH(vertex):  is D-C-A (correct with you)
    SHORTEST PATH(edge):  is edgeD-C, edgeC-A  (is your #11:4, #11:1)

[image]

Using the code, automatically extracts the shortest path (using the specific function of orient) and consequently the extraction of edges that are contained in this path. The only thing the manual, is that I put in V1 and V2 RID vertices Start and End.

**EDIT 4**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code (with 13 Million node database) and got the result in 3461 Milliseconds. I also used simple method and it was faster (3313 Milliseconds) beside I have the edges label. Firstly I get the vertexes and then: ( Iterable<Edge> vet = first_vertex.getEdges(second_vertex,Direction.valueOf("BOTH")); for (Edge edge : vet) { System.out.println(edge) . : } What you think ? is this is the best way to get it in OrientDB?  more than 3 seconds is little slow? especially when the path is longer then the computation time will be much longer–

Comment: I edited answer, on your DB how long it takes using this optimization??
I'm trying the BOTH suggestion you wrote me before. Update later.

Comment: I tested again with larger query result. Your method was better (3377 Milliseconds), mine (3487 Milliseconds). However, what is still missing in your method is the edge label. Could you add it so I can test it again.

Comment: When I have the graph: A-->F , F-->E, E-->D, D-->C, C-->A and I want to find the shortest path between "A" and "D" using your method, I got no edges: SHORTEST PATH (vertex): A C D SHORTEST PATH (edge): shouldn't the SHORTEST PATH (vertex) be: A, F, E, D ?. If I want to find the shortest path between "D" and "A", then no problem: SHORTEST PATH (vertex): D C A SHORTEST PATH (edge): #11:4 #11:1.  In my method I have to use “OUT” in order to get the correct short path: A-F-E-D.  Is there is a way to make this automatic only short path with constant relationship direction will be obtained.

Comment: I inserted the label of the edge. That's what you needed?

Comment: I try to check with the situation you've written with new vertices.

Comment: I tested, with the EDIT 3 i have the sorthest path with edge from A to D (the same as before) and D to A. Why A, F, E, D? It is not the shortest path (with vertex or with the edge).. is it correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately now I get no edges for both scenarios. I think the issue is to define which direction we would like to follow "IN" or "OUT". Therefore, tempIN and TempOUT should be checked. In the code I use you can define which direction you would like to follow, if "In" the path between "A" and "D" is ACD. If "out" then A-F-E-D. I updated my question and inserted the graph I have so you can check.

Comment: With edit4 I have summarized the cases, I'm changing the code so that there is not anything that you have to change (in, out, etc ..) so that automatically do it all alone. Just modified write it.

Comment: With the new code (see new answeer) are correct edges return? and it is always fast enough?